# Unity sciprtableobject containing just a list of 2 element arrays

Tags: arrays, list, unity-game-engine, scriptable-object

I'm attempting to put a list of 2 element arrays into a scriptable object. I've finally managed to avoid all compiler issues, but I'm not getting anything to populate in the inspector. I'm thinking I should just throw the SO out the window and create an 2D array. here's the entire class:

```
[SerializeField]
public static List<string[,]> list = new List<string[,]>();
```

Goal:

- List:

1. string, string
2. string, string
3. and on...

It's been a while since I've played with unity and I'm just trying to make a simple data container. Am I missing something simple?

Comment: If you only want 2 entries per array, a fixed array with string[] is needed, where you assign each entry new string[2]. But if you really just want two strings per entry in the list, why are you not creating a type that holds the strings, like a class or a tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not showing up in the inspector for two reasons:

1. You cannot see static values in the inspector.
2. Unity does not serialize lists of arrays.

If you need to have a list of two strings visible in the inspector, I would suggest creating a new object to define what it is you are listing.

For example, if you wanted to list items with a name and a description then you could do something like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Test SO", menuName = "Test SO")]
public class TestSO : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
}

[Serializable]
public class Item
{
    public string Name;
    public string Description;
}
```

Notice the `[Serializable]` attribute from the `System` namespace above the `Item` class. This allows your custom classes to show up in the inspector as well to be serialized elsewhere.

It looks like this in the inspector with a nice little handle to add and remove items:
[image: Inspector for test scriptable object]

I hope this clears things up!

Comment: Thanks, I tried that without [Serializable] and wasn't sure why nothing happened either. After looking up that attribute I came across the rules for serialization. I'll tinker with this and see if a SO is what I need or not, but thanks for answering my question!

Link for reference if anyone needs it later: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html